# Esperar la respuesta desde una API

Tags: api, hilos, twitter

Estoy usando la libreria Tweetinvi para la API de twitter, soy nueva en programación, así que me preguntaba si alguien me podría orientar o decirme como se llama el siguiente concepto a fin de poder leer acerca y poder aprender al respecto.

Supongo que la mayoría usais Twitter, me preguntaba como podría monitorizar y analizar la llegada de una respuesta en la que me mencionen, con la libreria no tengo problema, sé obtener las menciones de los últimos tweets, y responder a dichas menciones, el problema está en lo ineficiente que sería eso.

Podría hacer que un Timer estuviera ejecutando código cada 5 minutos, en busca de las nuevas menciones, sin embargo, eso implicaría que como máximo el tiempo de respuesta entre mención, sería de cinco minutos, por no hablar de los Rate-limite que tinen las APIS.

Ahora bien, ¿cómo podría ejecutar X código, solo y únicamente en el momento en el que soy mencionada a un tweet? ¿Cómo puedo detectar la llegada de esa mencion de manera instantanea, sin tener que ejecutar código constantemente en busca de nuevas menciones? Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Personalmente nunca he trabajo con esa librería aunque si que tengo bastante experiencia con Tweepy (para Python).

Hay una cosa que son los Stream. La librería que usas también los tiene ( https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Streams ). Esto lo hace es tener una conexión siempre abierta y está a la espera de nuevos eventos (tweets) según el filtro que uses.

Con esto y un filtro adecuado podrías controlar todas las menciones a tu usuario.
Creo que esta sería la opción más eficiente para lo que planteas.

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Lamento responderte tarde!, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, eso era lo que estaba buscando, voy a preguntarte una cosa a mayores, ¿qué pasa con las APIS que no tienen Live data? (Hablo de esta en concreto: https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/, y de sus siguientes dos librerias: 

https://github.com/MingweiSamuel/Camille 

https://github.com/BenFradet/RiotSharp

aunque si que diría que si que debería haber alguna forma de conseguir el LiveData porque lo he visto en otros prorgamas...)
Gracias una vez más por tu ayuda, y lamento la molestia.

Comment: Nada, gracias a ti! Pues si las APIs no lo permiten diría que la única forma de hacerlo es mediante llamadas cada X tiempo (como mencionabas en la pregunta) teniendo en cuenta el límite de peticiones de cada API para no hacer más peticiones de las que puedes.